# How to verify pact from consumer tests

Tags: pact

I have a consumer service and a provider service, the PACT is published in the PACT Broker between the consumer and provider.

I can verify pact from the Provider side for every build using
 mvn pact:verify

At the consumer service side whenever I need to run the tests I would use mocked data,How can I verify the pact from the consumer tests to ensure my mocked data is still relevant?

Regards,
Asif

Comment: Can you please explain why this matters and what problem you're having/seeing? i.e. why won't the mock data stay relevant, and why this is important?

Comment: A Provider on GET request, responds with body **"{City:Delhi}"**                            A consumer writes a mock to simulate the above response and publishes the PACT  to the PACT Broker                                                                                    Lets assume that the Provider response is changed to **{Town:Delhi}**  , how will the Consumer know that the pact is no more valid?

Comment: It doesn't need to know, if the provider does this it would break the contract and fail their build. Consumer never knows because the change doesn't go out

Answer (score 1):

This is the essence of contract testing.

The answer is that the consumer won't know if the provider breaks the contract, because the *provider would never release a change that is incompatible with it in the first place*. When a consumer publishes expectations of the provider through an agreed workflow, then it is incumbent on the provider to meet those expectations until they change (hopefully also via an agreed process, probably involving communication between the two teams).

Read more best practices at docs.pact.io

Comment: After your comment I did a similar excercise with Spring Cloud Contract, where Provider and Consumer were configured to a central maven and the Consumer was using the stubs generated by the Provider, the provider changed the contract and stubs were redefined and the consumer tests failed, which means the consumer is informed unlike pact?

Comment: Sure, they are different models though. We take a different approach: It would be pretty annoying if your code stopped working because a provider changed something